# Shell script to delete files when disk is full

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a small little script to clear space on my linux everyday via CRON if the cache directory grows too large.
Since I am really green at bash scripting, I will need a little bit of help from you linux gurus out there.

Here is basically the logic (pseudo-code)

```
    if ( Drive Space Left < 5GB )
    {
        change directory to '/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/'

        if ( current working directory = '/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/')
        {
            delete files in /home/user/lotsa_cache_files/
        }
    }
```

## Getting drive space left

I plan to get the drive space left from the '/dev/sda5' command.
If returns the following value to me for your info :

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on<br>
/dev/sda5            225981844 202987200  11330252  95% /
```

So a little regex might be necessary to get the '11330252' out of the returned value

## A little paranoia

The 'if ( current working directory = /home/user/lotsa_cache_files/)' part is just a defensive mechanism for the paranoia within me. I wanna make sure that I am indeed in '/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/' before I proceed with the delete command which is potentially destructive if the current working directory is not present for some reason.

## Deleting files

The deletion of files will be done with the command below instead of the usual rm -f:

```
find . -name "*" -print | xargs rm
```

This is due to the inherent inability of linux systems to 'rm' a directory if it contains too many files, as I have learnt in the past.

Comment: "inherent inability of linux systems to 'rm' a directory if it contains too many files" Does that also imply to "rm -rf"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just another proposal (comments within code):

```
FILESYSTEM=/dev/sda1 # or whatever filesystem to monitor
CAPACITY=95 # delete if FS is over 95% of usage 
CACHEDIR=/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/

# Proceed if filesystem capacity is over than the value of CAPACITY (using df POSIX syntax)
# using [ instead of [[ for better error handling.
if [ $(df -P $FILESYSTEM | awk '{ gsub("%",""); capacity = $5 }; END { print capacity }') -gt $CAPACITY ]
then
    # lets do some secure removal (if $CACHEDIR is empty or is not a directory find will exit
    # with error which is quite safe for missruns.):
    find "$CACHEDIR" --maxdepth 1 --type f -exec rm -f {} \;
    # remove "maxdepth and type" if you want to do a recursive removal of files and dirs
    find "$CACHEDIR" -exec rm -f {} \;
fi
```

Call the script from crontab to do scheduled cleanings

Comment: I suggest using the `-delete` flag instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`. Also consider adding `-xdev` as the first flag to stay in the same filesystem.

Comment: If you want to keep the latest files, I suggest : `find "$CACHEDIR" -type f -mmin +720 -delete` to delete only files older than 12 hours (*60 min = 720).

Answer (score 10):

I would do it this way:

```
# get the available space left on the device
size=$(df -k /dev/sda5 | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')

# check if the available space is smaller than 5GB (5000000kB)
if (($size<5000000)); then
  # find all files under /home/user/lotsa_cache_files and delete them
  find /home/user/lotsa_cache_files -name "*" -delete
fi
```

Comment: That's what I was going to recommend: Hard code the directory in the `find` command and don't use xargs because it can be dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the script I use to delete old files in a directory to free up space...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  prune_dir - prune directory by deleting files if we are low on space
#
DIR=$1
CAPACITY_LIMIT=$2

if [ "$DIR" == "" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: directory not specified"
    exit 1
fi

if ! cd $DIR
then
    echo "ERROR: unable to chdir to directory '$DIR'"
    exit 2
fi

if [ "$CAPACITY_LIMIT" == "" ]
then
    CAPACITY_LIMIT=95   # default limit
fi

CAPACITY=$(df -k . | awk '{gsub("%",""); capacity=$5}; END {print capacity}')

if [ $CAPACITY -gt $CAPACITY_LIMIT ]
then
    #
    # Get list of files, oldest first.
    # Delete the oldest files until
    # we are below the limit. Just
    # delete regular files, ignore directories.
    #
    ls -rt | while read FILE
    do
        if [ -f $FILE ]
        then
            if rm -f $FILE
            then
                echo "Deleted $FILE"

                CAPACITY=$(df -k . | awk '{gsub("%",""); capacity=$5}; END {print capacity}')

                if [ $CAPACITY -le $CAPACITY_LIMIT ]
                then
                    # we're below the limit, so stop deleting
                    exit
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Please check again the code! It seems that it will delete files within the current folder.

Comment: @Max it does `cd $DIR` so it won't.

Answer (score 3):

To detect the occupation of a filesystem, I use this :

```
df -k $FILESYSTEM | tail -1 | awk '{print $5}'
```

that gives me the occupation percentage of the filesystem, this way, I don't need to compute it :)

If you use bash, you can use the pushd/popd operation to change directory and be sure to be in.

```
pushd '/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/'
do the stuff
popd
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I do:

`while read f; do rm -rf ${f}; done < movies-to-delete.txt`