# Delete oldest files at full disk

Tags: python, wrapper

An application that writes data to disk in 100MB chunks and increments the file-name by appending +1, so `n1, n2 ... n1000`. This eventually uses all of the free space on the partition (Linux host). I am looking for a way to delete files that were first written in the series until the drive space is under a specific utilization.

If the latter, would https://stackoverflow.com/a/5912404/666891 be a good solution?

The following solution was proposed and looks to be a viable solution per https://stackoverflow.com/a/837840/666891. How could this be modified to handle the incrementing file extension as currently when the script is run it does not delete files name filename*, asterisk being the incrementing number, start with the oldest one?

```
import os
def free_space_up_to(free_bytes_required="161061273600", rootfolder="/data/", ex
tension="filename-*"):
    file_list= files_to_delete(rootfolder, extension)
    while file_list:
        statv= os.statvfs(rootfolder)
        if statv.f_bfree*statv.f_bsize >= free_bytes_required:
            break
        os.remove(file_list.pop())
```

Comment: I believe the bash script you linked is a good solution.

Comment: The script you linked to appears to delete the entire directory, not the lowest-numbered files.

Comment: Is there only one filename prefix to worry about? eg `n` or do you need to consider other prefixes too?

Comment: if you decide to go the python route this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837606/find-the-oldest-file-recursively-in-a-directory

Comment: The python logging module's [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) already does something similar to what the OP requires, though it may not be possible to convert the existing code to use the log ging module.

Comment: @gnibbler Only one but it increments. Secondly, the file extension may not always end with .ext, it may be -ext but I believe that is trivial.

Comment: @johnthexiii The example in that question looks promising, question updated.

Comment: The cited python code should work for you: the files are sorted by the age of the file - which in your case is the same than looking for the filename.

Comment: The cited code does not seem to be working and it is not providing syntactical errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you know that all files are (at least sort of) 100MB in size, and assuming there's nothing else drastically altering disk usage on the machine, you don't need to check for free space at every iteration.

Also, if all files have the same name, besides the counter at the end, you can skip the os.stat call (which could also be useless for files created in quick succession) and sort on the filenames based on the counter:

```
import os

def free_space_up_to(free_bytes_required=161061273600, rootfolder="/data/", filesize=104857600, basename="filename-"):
    '''Deletes rootfolder/basename*, oldest first, until there are free_bytes_required available on the partition.
    Assumes that all files have file_size, and are all named basename{0,1,2,3,...}
    Returns number of deleted files.
    '''
    statv = os.statvfs(rootfolder)
    required_space = free_bytes_required - statv.f_bfree*statv.f_bsize
    basepath = os.path.join(rootfolder, basename)
    baselen = len(basepath)
    if required_space <= 0:
        return 0

    # "1 +" here for quickly rounding
    files_to_delete = 1 + required_space/filesize

    # List all matching files. If needed, replace with os.walk for recursively
    # searching into subdirectories of rootfolder
    file_list = [os.path.join(rootfolder, f) for f in os.listdir(rootfolder)
                 if f.startswith(basename)]

    file_list.sort(key=lambda i: int(i[baselen:]), reverse=True)
    # Alternatively, if the filenames can't be trusted, sort based on modification time
    #file_list.sort(key=lambda i: os.stat(i).st_mtime)

    for f in file_list[:files_to_delete]:
        os.remove(f)
    return files_to_delete
```

(Not thoroughly tested, I recommend a test run substituting "os.remove" with "print" ;))

Comment: That is what I am looking for. Tried running it, changing the `os.remove` to `print` and there is no response. Also tried changing `file_list.sort` to use modification time without any improvement. Any ideas or debugging tips?

Comment: Note that, if the required space is already present, the function exits (returning 0, that is, no files needed to be deleted). Put a print statement before the "return 0" to see if this is what's happening.

Try passing a bigger number to free_bytes_required, so that the function will actually need to remove some files.

Comment: Added print statement before `return 0` but still no output and increased size to amount greater than free space available. Any other debugging tips?

Comment: Well, how are you running it? I don't know what your Python knowledge is, but if you simply paste the code above in a file and execute "python file.py", it will not execute the function. You need to either add a call to the function at the end of the file (unindented), or open the Python prompt, import the function and execute it manually.

Comment: I was calling the function but realized that the filesize needed to be adjusted. Thanks for the insight and answer!