# Python script to find and delete oldest files until free HDD space threshold is met

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, delete-file

I'm absolutely brand new to Python, and though I've done a bit of searching already (and have found a few good answers) I'm still having issues getting a script that's supposed to do exactly this to work. That is, I'd like the script to delete the oldest files in a given directory one by one until the 100GiB free space threshold is met. I'm currently getting the following error:

```
  File "./freespace.py", line 18, in <module>
    free_space_up_to(107374182400, "/home/hindenpeter/Downloads/")
  File "./freespace.py", line 13, in free_space_up_to
    statv=os.fstatvfs(rootfolder)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

when attempting to run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import os
def files_to_delete(rootfolder):
    return sorted(
        (os.path.join(dirname, filename)
         for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfolder)
         for filename in filenames),
            key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime),reversed==True
def free_space_up_to(free_bytes_required, rootfolder):
    file_list=files_to_delete(rootfolder)
    while file_list:
        statv=os.fstatvfs(rootfolder)
        if statv.f_bfree*statv.f_bsize >= free_bytes_required:
            break
        os.remove(file_list.pop())

free_space_up_to(107374182400, "/home/hindenpeter/Downloads/")
```

So I'm looking for help getting this to work properly (also, a translation of what exactly the error means would be awesome!), or perhaps a completely new script that will do what I'd like.

For reference, these are the most relevant posts I found pertaining to my issue:
[Delete oldest files at full disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815661/delete-oldest-files-at-full-disk)
[Find the oldest file (recursively) in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837606/find-the-oldest-file-recursively-in-a-directory)

Comment: Apparently the error is thrown when the path does not exists

Comment: Yes, as it turns out I should have been using os.statvfs all along, as Yann suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fstatvfs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fstatvfs) requires a file descriptor (as returned by [file.fileno()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno)), for a path name you want to use [statvfs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.statvfs).

Comment: Ahh, perfect! That seems to work perfectly! Many thanks for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `fstatvfs` takes a *file descriptor* (an integer) as an argument, and not a path. You should call [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#open) on the path first, and then pass the resulting object's *descriptor* (via the `fileno()` method) to `fstatvfs`.

Also, another option that would not require getting a *file descriptor* first, and can use the path directly, would be calling [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat). You would then want to look at the `st_size` attribute.

Comment: It's not as easy to open a directory; os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY, os.O_DIRECTORY) can do it on some GNU systems, but the main reason to do it that way is to avoid errors if the directory is moved or removed.

Comment: You would call `open` to get the `file` object on which to call `fileno`, right?

Comment: Directories are different from normal files, and many systems don't allow you to open them the same way (you'll get the "Is a directory" error). The O_DIRECTORY flag is a GNU extension signifying that you really want to open a directory. The standard way is calling opendir(), which AFAIK doesn't exist in Python's standard library. Since the most common reason to open one is to list its contents, we have os.listdir and os.walk for easier access.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, I probably would've gotten the size of each individual file in the directory, recursively, using `os.walk` and summed them up, as opposed to trying to get metadata from the directory itself.

Comment: That is how you get the disk usage of the directory; the question was about free space, where the file system statistics are necessary. statvfs is the right call.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some test is appear that `os.fstatvfs` throw this error when the specified path doesn't exists. Which would be coherent with the internal need for a file descriptor.