# How do I get remaining space for current use in a shell script?

Tags: unix, ssh

Okay so I'm writing a shell script that will need to delete files if available space is running low, however I don't know how to retrieve the remaining space in such a way that quotas will be taken into account (if set).

For example, I could use the df command, however this only seems to retrieve actual block usage for a file-system, so it will report the total free space for the entire volume, even if a user's quota will prevent the script from being to use that much space.

Is there a command that I can use that will retrieve the minimum free space remaining for the current user's quota or the volume's free space (whichever is lower)?

[edit]
Okay, so it looks like the quota command can get me the information I need, the problem I'm now having is getting the useful data out of it for all possible return values. When called with no quota set it will simply return "none", which means I then need to delve into df to get size.

Can anyone help with a script for querying quota then df (if needed) to get a current usage and maximum block-size (either by quota or volume, whichever is lowest/set) so that I can then calculate an amount of remaining space?

Comment: Looks like there's already an answer for your question,follow the below thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908919/newbie-needs-help-with-bash-scripting-shell-script-to-delete-files-when-disk-i

Comment: @SanthoshPai That doesn't appear to take quotas into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the script I came up with in the end; it should fairly reliably return either the file-system's remaining space (in bytes) or the user's remaining quota for the same file-system. It's not massively quick as looking up the correct /dev/foo path for use with `quota` is more involved than I would like.

```
#!/bin/sh
freespace_remaining() {
    # Get remaining space on file-system
    fs=$(df -k "$1" | tail -1)
    free=$(echo "$fs" | awk '{ print $4 }')
    let 'free *= 1024'

    # Determine the device for the file-system
    device=
    mnt=$(echo "$fs" | awk '{ print $6 }')
    if [ "$cached_mnt" != "$mnt" ] 
        then
            cached_mnt="$mnt"

            mnts=$(mount)
            newmnt="$mnt"

            # Try to get a root mount point (for encrypted folders etc.)
            while [ -n "$newmnt" ] 
            do
                newmnt=$(echo "$mnts" | grep " on $mnt " | awk '{ print $1 }')
                [ "$newmnt" = "$mnt" ] && break

                if [ -n "$newmnt" ] 
                    then
                        device="$newmnt"
                        mnt=$(df "$newmnt" 2> /dev/null | tail -1 | awk '{print $6 }')

                        [ "$mnt" = "$device" -o "$mnt" = "$last" ] && break
                        last="$mnt"
                fi
            done

            cached_device="$device"
    fi

    # Lookup the user's quota for the target device (if any is set)
    quota=$(quota | grep "[\s]*$device")

    # Return the lower of the two values as remaining space
    if [ -n "$quota" ]
        then
            quota=$(echo "$quota" | awk '{ print $3 }')
            used=$(echo "$quota" | awk '{ print $2 }')

            let 'quota=(quota - used) * 1024'
            [ "$quota" -lt "$free" ] && free="$quota"
    fi
    echo "$free"
}

freespace_remaining "$1"
```

Hopefully it's clear enough how it works, just pass in a path as the first (and only) argument and it'll return the freespace remaining, with the current user's quota (if any) taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to find the occupation of filesystem,try once and see.

```
df -k /*somedirectoryname
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I think that's what I was trying before; it doesn't report remaining space with my quota taken into account, just returns remaining space for the entire volume. So if there's 500gb of free space then that's what it returns, even if I only have a remaining quota of 10gb.